# Производительность jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, jupyter-notebook

Я пользуюсь jupyter notebook при работе с данными, наукой о данных занимаюсь недавно.

Подскажите пожалуйста основной инструментарий, который стоит использовать? Иногда когда пытаюсь строить графики в jupyter он может зависнуть или вовсе остановить ядро. Jupyter вообще подходит для визуализации и обучения относительно большого количества данных или стоит использовать другой инструмент?

Comment: проблема скорее всего возникает при отрисовке больших массивов данных, т.е. в `matplotlib`. Покажите код, вызывающий проблему и пример данных, который позволил бы воспроизвести проблему... PS а вообще Jupyter идеально подходит для ваших задач (конечно пока хватает оперативной памяти)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Инструмент - в данном случае IDE - это всегда дело вкуса (и текущей моды). Мне, например, больше по душе Spyder.

Основное преимущество Jupyter я нахожу во-первых в том, что он как бы имеет web-интерфейс, во-вторых в том, что позволяет создавать свои "блоктноты". Ни то ни другое для меня представляется не крадинальным, но с моей точки зрения на производительность влияет не в лучшую сторону. Spyder в свою очередь  весьма популярен у тех кто занимается Data Science, собственно для этой ниши он и проектировался.

И у того инструмента и у другого ( и у других IDE для Python) есть свои приверженцы. Это говорит о том, что они все нормально справляются с большинством задач, которые встречаются в DS и в общем-то основная проблема не в IDE а в hardware- ресурсах вашего компьютера.

Answer (score 1):

При использовании jupyter notebook производительность зависит от сложности самих вычислений и мощности железки, на которой вы всё запускаете.
По части стабильности - всё ок, даже ребята из ЦЕРН его используют для своих расчётов.

Для отрисовки графиков рекомендую взглянуть также на [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/).